# Netzke controller generation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs4, netzke

i'm new to Ruby and Rails and asking about error while generating simple controller 
http://writelesscode.com/blog/2012/10/20/extjs-rails-crud-application-in-7-minutes/

```
$ rails g controller welcome index
```

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/netzke-core-0.8.2/lib/netzke/core/railz.rb:2:in `require': /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/netzke-core-0.8.2/lib/netzke/core/railz/routes.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
...refix}/:action(.:format)", to: controller.to_s, as: 'netzke'
                              ^
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/netzke-core-0.8.2/lib/netzke/core/railz/routes.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '='
...at)", to: controller.to_s, as: 'netzke'
                              ^
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/netzke-core-0.8.2/lib/netzke/core/railz.rb:2
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/netzke-core-0.8.2/lib/netzke-core.rb:10:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/netzke-core-0.8.2/lib/netzke-core.rb:10
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /Users/sparta/Work/rails/erp/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in`require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:24
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6

Maybe something wrong with routes? What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using Ruby 1.8.7. Netzke requires 1.9.x.